# slideToggle not pushing down lower div

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I'm having some trouble getting jQuery's slideToggle to push down the div beneath the toggled div. There are multiple existing posts on this issue, but the answer generally seems to be that the divs must be position: relative, which is already the case. I know that the culprit is the wrapper div class="content" but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's affecting the behavior and thus how to go about fixing it.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elliotstarks/dsphqosc/1/) demo.

Also, here's my code in a Stack Snippet:

```js
$(".toggle-control").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".toggle-section").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden-section {
  display: none;
}
.content {
  max-width: 945px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f3eee2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #333;
  padding: 0 18px 20px 18px;
  min-height: 626px;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
}
.content #mockup1 {
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-image {
  width: 540px;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-details {
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-details .package-details--header {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 25px;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-details .package-details--list {
  list-style: none;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-details .package-details--list li {
  padding: 0;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  background-color: #f9f5ea;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--from {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--per {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--dropdown {
  float: right;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--dropdown .package-rates--view {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates .package-rates--dropdown .caret {
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px dashed;
}
.content #mockup1 .package-rates:hover {
  background-color: #e9e0c9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="mockup" id="mockup1">

    <img class="package-image" src="http://cdn4.bluefieldsvillas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/san-michele-3.jpg" />

    <div class="package-details">

      <h2 class="package-details--header">San Michele</h2>

      <ul class="package-details--list">
        <li>Available</li>
        <li>6 Rooms</li>
        <li>Private Pool</li>
        <li>Saturday - Saturday</li>
        <li>
          <br />Included Packages:
          <ul>
            <li>All Inclusive</li>
            <li>Airport Transportation</li>
            <li>Club Mobay</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <br />Available Packages:
          <ul>
            <li>Wedding</li>
            <li>Vow Renewal</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="package-rates toggle-control">

      <span class="package-rates--from">From</span>
      <span class="package-rates--price">$234</span>
      <span class="package-rates--per">/ Person / Night</span>
      <span class="package-rates--dropdown">
                    <span class="package-rates--view">View Rates</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </span>

      <div class="toggle-section hidden-section">
        <ul>
          <li>foo</li>
          <li>bar</li>
          <li>baz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div style="height:200px; background-color:green;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't actually the positioning of your elements, but the static dimensions you're defining for them - which conflicts with the dynamic nature of your `.toggle-section` element.

On `.content #mockup1 .package-rates` (the parent of the element you're manipulating), you've specified `height: 40px` - meaning that regardless of how tall its children are, it will be treated by neighbouring elements as always having a height of 40px.

If you want the element to be at least 40px, but also grow to accommodate its children should they be taller, consider using `min-height` instead:

```
.content #mockup1 .package-rates {
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  background-color: #f9f5ea;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsphqosc/2/). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much! I knew it was probably something simple, but spent much too long on troubleshooting it and had hit a wall.

Comment: Glad I could help out! Sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes looking at the code...

Answer (score 1):

In `.content #mockup1 .package-rates` you set `height: 40px;`

Setting the height on this div makes it impossible for the `.toggle-section` to push the the div down

Remove this line and it will work

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue.

Comment: Glad I almost helped out! Sometimes all you need to not being able to help is another person writing a better detailed answer in the same time ;)